# ¿Cómo mostrar cadenas de caracteres en PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito mostrar solo las 3 primeras palabras de una consulta sql.

En mi base de datos tengo una columna de descripción de un producto por ejemplo **TOMA INDUST. B/SUPERFICIAL TRIF. DE 63A.** y lo que quiero es que cuando lo imprima solo aparezca **TOMA INDUST. B/SUPERFICIAL.**

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM sinventario,as_precios WHERE sinventario.FI_CODIGO = as_precios.FI_CODIGO
```

Guardo los datos en array

```
$FI_DESCRIPCION = $filas['FI_DESCRIPCION'];
```

y los imprimo de esta manera

```
<?php echo $FI_DESCRIPCION;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder separar la cadena podrías usar la función `explode()` por ejemplo:

```
$pizza  = "porción1 porción2 porción3 porción4 porción5 porción6";
$porciones = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $porciones[0]; // imprimirá porción1
echo $porciones[1]; // imprimirá porción2
```

En tu caso sería:

```
$aux = "TOMA INDUST. B/SUPERFICIAL TRIF. DE 63A.";
$str = explode(" ", $aux);
echo $str[0]." ".$str[1]." ".$str[2]; // eso imprimirá: TOMA INDUST. B/SUPERFICIAL
```

Comment: listo gracias por tu ayuda juan

Answer (score 1):

En el caso que quieras mejorar el codigo podes utilizar un for, y ademas, contar cuantos elementos tiene el array, por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
$elarreglo = explode(" ", $elstring);
$arreglo_len = min( count($elarreglo), 3); // Por si el arreglo no es mas grande
for($i=0; $i < $arr_length; $i++)
{
    echo $elarreglo[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usa explode para obtener los elementos, el tercer parámetro te da el máximo de elementos

```
$els = explode(' ',$FI_DESCRIPCION,4 ); // el ultimo elemento (cuarto) tiene lo que sobra
```

con slice te aseguras que tenga no mas de 3 elementos

```
$els3 = slice( $els,0,3);
```

con implode juntas los elementos en un string

```
  $elsstring = implode( ' ', $els3 );
```

luego lo muestras:

```
echo $elstring;
```

en una línea

```
echo implode( ' ', slice( explode(' ',$FI_DESCRIPCION,4 ),0,3) );
```